# Kill any GS process that's been running for over 5m on CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, process, kill

Hi our server has a weird issue where once a month or so a GS (GhostScript) process gets stuck and eats 10-75% CPU until I kill the process. strace hasn't provided anything useful so until I can resolve this correctly I'd like to create a script that checks every few minutes and kills any GS process that has been running for longer than 5 minutes. Under normal circumstances this process should complete in a few seconds to a minute at most.

In top the command shows up as "GS". How do I go about doing this? I'm assuming I need to write a BASH script as well as set it to run on an interval? The box is a webserver running CentOS 6.5.

Thanks!

Comment: What spawns the ghostscript process? I'd really take the approach of fixing the root issue... can you give more information about the application?

Comment: We use PrinceXML to generate PDF's through their PHP wrapper. I pass an HTML file, Prince converts it to a PDF using GhostScript for font rendering. I don't call GS myself it's done through their API.

From the logs I can tell which account/file caused GS to hang, but once I kill the process I can re-run the export and it works every time.

The only clue that may be causing it, and I'm not sure if this is actually the case, is if a user clicks repeatedly I cancel the AJAX call that requests a PDF and resend. Perhaps cancelling the request it causing it to occasionally hang?

Comment: I've tested cancelling AJAX calls and I haven't been able to replicate the hang.

Answer (score 2):

Use killall command as follow,
Replace Process_Name with the GS process name,

```
killall  --older-than 5m Process_Name
```

To create a script file

```
touch myscript.sh

chmod +x myscript.sh

echo "killall  --older-than 5m Process_Name" > myscript.sh
```

To run the script every 5 mins, Assuming myscript is located in the root directory.

```
echo "*/5 * * * * /root/myscript.sh" >> /etc/crontab
```

Comment: `killall --older-than` is not present in CentOS or RHEL systems.

Comment: @ewwhite Does CentOS have an equivalent?